# Can I make Evolution to automatically check emails when I launch it?

Tags: evolution, email

By default when Evolution is launched, I have to press the button "Check emails" (or press <kbd>F9</kbd>) to receive new emails. I would like it to be automatic each time I launch Evolution. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evolution checks for new mail for every account that you have set up automatic email checking. To turn on automatic email checking:

1. Navigate to *Edit ➜ Preferences ➜ Mail Accounts ➜ select one of your accounts ➜ Edit ➜ Receiving Options*, check the *Check for new messages every XX minutes* and set the time interval to whatever you want.

   > [image]
   > If you don't want Evolution to check mail automatically, set the time interval to the maximum `1440` minutes. This will cause Evolution check for new mail 24 hours after you start it up, most likely you will have either shutdown your computer or quit Evolution by then.
2. Repeat step 1 for every account you want to check the mail for on startup.

Comment: Thank you for answering but it is not what I want to do. Your solution would check for new emails every XX minutes. I just want to check for new emails once, when I first launch Evolution.

Comment: @Gizmoatwork: This is the only way to make evolution check mail right after launch, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/evolution/+bug/13973. If you set the time interval to the maximum (2400 minutes) it will only check once every 24 hours, which means that for all intents and and purposes, it doesn't check for email automatically.

Comment: You are right. The option label is confusing and misleading. But at least it does the job.